# How to complete the task 1 time for one user

Tags: python-2.7, locust

I write a little task, and want to simulate 100 users, but i want to complete it 1 time for 1 user. Example: my task has 2 requests, so in total i want get 2 * 100 requests. I may stop it manually, but how to do it automatically?.

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for can be achieved by using a TaskSequence in locust.

Have a look on official documentation: https://docs.locust.io/en/stable/writing-a-locustfile.html#tasksequence-class

```py
class MyTaskSequence(TaskSequence):
    @seq_task(1)
    @task(1)
    def given_task(self):
        pass
```